# Flutter how to open page from push notification, context issue

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

```
void selectNotification(String? payload) async {
    print('Selected notification');
    Navigator.of(context).push(
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => SearchScreen(),
      ),
    );
  }
```

I am using this method to open a screen when the notification is tapped, I get the print message fine but then the Navigator message shows:

```
The context used to push or pop routes from the Navigator must be that of a widget that is a descendant of a Navigator widget.
```

Im just trying to have it so if the notificaiton is tapped from foreground, background where ever the app then just pops open that screen but I cant get it to work

Comment: You should provide more information about the code.
For example, where is this method defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void selectNotification(String? payload, BuildContext context) async {
    print('Selected notification');
    Navigator.of(context).push(
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => SearchScreen(),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Provide some more information about this code so that everyone can understand.

Answer (score 0):

Use getX package and use navigation routing:
something like this:
`Get.put(()=> **your page**`

[getX package](https://pub.dev/packages/get)